# How to connect TPM and UART serial connection with Raspberry Pi 4 at same and access TPM in u-boot

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, embedded, uart, tpm

I want to connect **Infineon 9665 tpm 2.0** with raspberry pi 4b and need to access TPM in the u-boot shell. To get u-boot shell, I need to have a serial connection. Right now, I am using a breadboard, connecting pins of rpi4 with breadboard and from breadboard to TPM and sort pin 6, 8, 10 with a serial connection to my laptop/pc.

I am not able to access tpm at all, not even in OS whenever connection is:  (here `->` stands for jumper cable)

> **`rpi -> breadboard -> tpm`**
> Got serial connection using uart0 but TPM is not detected in u-boot shell as well as in OS, similar to [this](https://github.com/joholl/rpi4-uboot-tpm/issues/7)

nor even in this case

> **`rpi -> tpm`**
> No serial connection so not able to get u-boot shell and, TPM is not
> detected in OS

When I directly connect TPM with rpi4, I am able to access it in OS but in that case, I am not able to get a serial connection because UART pins are covered by TPM.

Then from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#configuring-uarts), I got to know that rpi4 has 5 UART connections so I am using UART5 (pin 32, 33), and the got the serial output but this output is starting from the kernel and not starting of u-boot.

Any help/workaround/suggestions regarding this are appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: "*rpi4 has 5 UART connections*" -- The typical SoC has far more peripherals on the silicon die than pin connections to the board.  So it's not possible to use the entire set of peripherals.  The peripherals you select to use must be individually enabled, and possibly multiplex the pins.  U-Boot by default will only enable a minimal set of peripherals to accomplish booting, but that can be expanded.

Comment: Yes, correct so I have already enabled TPM inside u-boot specifically while compiling it. Basically, the main need here is how to connect the serial console as well as TPM simultaneously.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Yes @Rob but it seems this connection also needs some script to be made that configures UART pins, so I posted it here.